# Adding System.Web.Script reference in class library

Tags: asp.net, namespaces, class-library

I am currently moving code from my app_code folder to a class library.  I have tagged several methods with `[System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnore]` attributes.  My class library cannot see this namespace.  My add references dialog cannot see this namespace.  How do I properly use this tag from a class library?

Here is the error:
*The type or namespace name 'ScriptIgnoreAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Answer (score 284, accepted):

The `ScriptIgnoreAttribute` class is in the **System.Web.Extensions.dll** assembly (Located under Assemblies > Framework in the VS Reference Manager). You have to add a reference to that assembly in your class library project.

You can find this information at top of the MSDN page for the [ScriptIgnoreAttribute class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx).

Comment: Nice one. `System.Web.Script.JavaScriptSerializer` is also in this assembly.

Comment: I love how the System.Web.Script.Serialization is in the System.Web.Extensions library.

Comment: it is not available in asp.net2

Comment: Make sure you are using .NET framework 4 not .NET Framework 4 client profile as the target framework, or System.Web.Extensions will not appear in the Add References dialog.

Comment: It's the year 2017, we're still in VS 2005 and this answer just saved my bacon. To infinity, and beyond!

Comment: How can i use serailizer & deserializer in JScript.NET?

Answer (score 19):

You need to add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions.dll` in project for System.Web.Script.Serialization error.

Answer (score 0):

I have been testing for .Net Framework V4.7 and have found the **`System.Web.Script`** namespace from the reference `System.Web.Extensions`

[image]