# How to reference JSON serialization in ClassLibrary?

Tags: c#, json

What library I need to reference to use `System.Web.Script.Serialization` in `Class Library`?

`System.Web` has been already referenced but using `System.Web.Script.Serialization`; still failed. Target Framework is 4.0. In WebApplication project everything is fine.

Comment: it is not a standalone library

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1156313/465053).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`System.Web.Extensions` is the assembly you need to reference.

For future reference, this information can be found on the majority of the MSDN Documentation pages. It is found directly under the Inheritance Hierarchy:

> **Namespace**:  System.Web.Script.Serialization
>   **Assembly**:  System.Web.Extensions (in System.Web.Extensions.dll)

[MSDN - JavaScriptSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)