# How can I do System.Web.Script.Serialization in C#?

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer, system.web, downloadstring

How can I do this in C# modern UI ?

```
var url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.digg.com%2Frss%2Findex.xml&v=1.0";
var wc = new WebClient();
var rawFeedData = wc.DownloadString(url);

//You can use System.Web.Script.Serialization if you don't want to use Json.NET
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
FeedApiResult foo = ser.Deserialize<FeedApiResult>(rawFeedData);

//Json.NET also return you the same strong typed object     
var apiResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeedApiResult>(rawFeedData);
```

It gives me error an error in WebClient and `System.Web.Script.Serialization`

Comment: 1. Could not find the type or namespace name "WebClient"      -   2. Could not find the type or namespace name "JavaScriptSerializer"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference JSON serialization in ClassLibrary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872734/how-to-reference-json-serialization-in-classlibrary)

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1156313/465053)

Answer (score 65):

I found how to make it work.
I don't know why they did this mess and I don't even understand why but here's the solution:
Right click on project and add reference to:

System.Web.Extensions

than you can add the reference you need with:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

and this time it will work. (At least this is what I did on .NET framework 3.5)

Comment: Worked in 4.0 as well.

Answer (score 5):

I found the System.Web.Script.Serialization   in
System.Web.Extensions