# Cannot find JavaScriptSerializer in .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jsonserializer

I cannot seem to find the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) object nor the the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace within Visual Studio 2010.  I need to serialize something to JSON what am I supposed to use?

And yes, I already included the `System.Web.Extensions` (in System.Web.Extensions.dll) within the project.  Which is why I am shocked?

- I do know `System.Web.Extensions` was marked as [obsolete](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2008/07/09/any-bets-on-whether-or-not-javascriptserializer-will-really-be-obsolete.aspx) in 3.5

Comment: I have the same problem, and I gotta say the answers are pretty useless. I am targeting the ".NET Framework 4", **not** ".NET 4 Client Profile". I **have** referenced the System.Web.Extensions assembly. But when I try using the System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace, VS 2010 tells me "The type or namespace Script does not exist in the namespace System.Web". Has anyone found a real solution for this? I'm stumped!

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1156313/465053).

Answer (score 544, accepted):

Check if you included the .net 4 version of `System.Web.Extensions` - there's a 3.5 version as well, but I don't think that one works.

These steps work for me:

1. Create a new console application
2. Change the target to .net 4 instead of Client Profile
3. Add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` (4.0)
4. Have access to `JavaScriptSerializer` in Program.cs now :-)

Comment: in vb.net don't forget "new" and ( ) like :  Dim JsonConvert As New JavaScriptSerializer()

Answer (score 141):

1. Right click `References` and do `Add Reference`, then from `Assemblies->Framework` select `System.Web.Extensions`.
2. Now you should be able to add the following to your class file:

```cs
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Answer (score 43):

From the first search result on google:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

> JavaScriptSerializer Class
>
> Provides serialization and deserialization functionality for AJAX-enabled applications.
>
> Inheritance Hierarchy
>
> System.Object
>
> System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
>
> Namespace:  System.Web.Script.Serialization
>
> Assembly:  System.Web.Extensions (in System.Web.Extensions.dll)

**So, include `System.Web.Extensions.dll` as a reference.**

Comment: Two years later, on a totally unrelated project: it also helps if you capitalize it correctly >.> (it's not JavascriptSerializer).

Answer (score 30):

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and finally ran across this post.

Yes in order to use

```
JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

You must right click on references and under Assemblies --> Framework choose

```
System.Web.Extensions
```

**Then add in your reference**

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Answer (score 15):

This is how to get JavaScriptSerializer available in your application, targetting `.NET 4.0` (full)

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

This should allow you to create a new `JavaScriptSerializer` object!

Comment: Script does not exist

Answer (score 13):

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

is in assembly :  System.Web.Extensions (System.Web.Extensions.dll)

Answer (score 9):

Are you targeting the .NET 4 framework or the .NET 4 Client Profile?

If you're targeting the latter, you won't find that class.  You also may be missing a reference, likely to an extensions dll.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.  And I already have 'System.Web.Extensions' included in the project

Comment: Is this a project you've upgraded from an earlier version of .net?

Comment: I'm having this issue with a project I upgraded. It doesn't appear to be resolved by using the original .net version (3.5) though...

Answer (score 9):

For those who seem to be following the answers above but still have the problem (e.g., see the first comment on the poster's question):

You are probably working in a solution with many projects.  The project you appear to be working in references other projects, but you are actually modifying a file from one of the other projects.  For example:

- project A references `System.Web.Extensions`
- project A references project B

But if the file you are modifying to use `System.Web.Script.Serialization` is in project B, then you will need to add a reference to `System.Web.Extension` in project B as well.

Answer (score 8):

Did you include a reference to `System.Web.Extensions`?  If you click on your first link it says which assembly it's in.

Comment: In that case maybe check out @Christopher's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add the reference to the project.

In Assemblies, there is a System.Web.Extensions Add that.

Once that is done put:

```
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Script;
    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use another option which is the Newtonsoft.Json, you can install it from NuGet Package Manager.

Tools >> Nuget Package Manager >> Package Manager Console by issuing command

`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

or

by using the GUI at Tools >> Nuget Package Manager >> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...

[image]

Comment: Note that this is Microsoft's [documented recommendation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer).  On .Net Core, Microsoft no longer even offers JavaScriptSerializer (nor the rest of System.Web.Extensions).

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know, I am using Visual Studio 2013 and have had the same problem until I used the Project Properties to switch to 3.5 framework and back to 4.5. This for some reason registered the .dll properly and I could use the **System.Web.Extensions**.

[image]

[image]