# error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Script' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, javascriptserializer, jsonserializer

I am trying to use `JavaScriptSerializer` in my application.

I initially received

> Cannot find JavaScriptSerializer

and I solved it by adding:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

But then the sub-keyword `Script` is underlined with a blue line:

> The type or namespace 'Script' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

So I added to the project a reference to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Web.Extensions.dll

That didn't help. I am still receiving the same blue underline with same error. The reference is marked with an exclamation mark yellow warning:

[image]

I tried the suggested solutions on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7000811/1088880), but as @user781490 indicated, they didn't help in my situation.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: So the framework your project is pointing is definitely NOT the Client Profile version, right?

Comment: As the user above me stated, make sure your project is targeting .NET 4 and not .NET 4 client profile.

Comment: @Arran It *is* a `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` but: **(1)** I am not interested in converting it to a `.NET Framework 4`. **(2)** If you read that thread, you'll notice that the tips there didn't help even for those who had the full `.NET Framework 4`. Surely there must be a way to use `JavaScriptSerializer` in a Client Profile, right?

Comment: @TejasSharma If I try to change the Target framework from `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile` to `.NET Framework 4`, I get a warning that horrible things might happen to my project... So when asked "Are you sure you want to change the Target Framework for this project?", of course I click `No`.

Comment: Have you tried deleting and then re-adding the System.Web.Extensions reference?

Comment: I've used DataContractJsonSerializer (which lives in the System.Runtime.Serialization.Json namespace) when I've not been able to use JavaScriptSerializer (such as in wcf projects).  Just a thought...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found [this MSDN forum post which suggests two solutions to your problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/55a12052-d352-4133-8fa5-52ad49bde64f).

First solution (not recommended):

> Find the .Net Framework 3.5 and 2.0 folder
>
> Copy  System.Web.Extensions.dll from 3.5 and  System.Web.dll from 2.0 to the application folder
>
> Add the reference to these two assemblies
>
> Change the referenced assemblies property, setting "Copy Local" to true
>   And build to test your application to ensure all code can work

Second solution (Use a different class / library):

The user who had posted the question claimed that [`Uri.EscapeUriString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapeuristring.aspx) and [How to: Serialize and Deserialize JSON Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx) helped him replicate the behavior of `JavaScriptSerializer`.

You could also try to use [Json.Net](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json). It's a third party library and pretty powerful.

Comment: Referencing the `3.5` version in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444903/how-to-install-json-net-using-nuget  newtonsoft.json is another option.

Answer (score 54):

I had the same. Script been underlined. I added a reference to System.Web.Extensions. Thereafter the Script was no longer underlined. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I have added  a reference to System.Web.Extensions , and now both of them are underlined

Answer (score 41):

Add System.Web.Extensions as a reference to your project

[image]

For Ref.

Comment: Please add steps on how to reach this menu.

Comment: @Adnan The menu can be reached via Project -> Add Reference.

Answer (score 7):

Just Add reference to System.Web.Extensions and happy to go.

Answer (score 1):

Since JsonSerializer is deprecated in .Net 4.0+ I used http://www.newtonsoft.com/json to solve this issue.

NuGet- > Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 0):

i have try it you could add reference web.extensions ( i using .Net framwork 4.5)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue.
Fail on "using System.Threading.Channels;"

my solution is to add reference of " System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"
[image: System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with two projects I'd made myself.
the problem was mismatching the .net framework version.