# node.js example edge module

Tags: c#, node.js, .net

I'm new in Node.js, and I use edge for my app.

In app.js I have this code

```
var edge = require('edge');

var helloWorld = edge.func(function () {/*
    async (input) => { 
        return ".NET Welcomes " + input.ToString(); 
    }
*/});

helloWorld('JavaScript', function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```

When i run it i have this error

> Exception non gérée : System.MissingMethodException: Méthode
>   introuvable : 'Bool ean
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnoreAttribute.get_ApplyToOverrides()
>   '.    à ClrFunc.MarshalCLRObjectToV8(Handle* , Object
>   netdata)    à ClrFunc.MarshalCLRExceptionToV8(Handle* ,
>   Exception exception)    à ClrFunc.Initialize(Handle* ,
>   Arguments* args)    à initializeClrFunc(Handle* ,
>   Arguments* args)

Have you any idea how solving this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please translate your error message to English? And this is a .NET Framework exception. Show your C# code as well.

Comment: Unhandled exception : System.MissingMethodException: method not found : 'Boolean System.Web.Script.Serialization.ScriptIgnoreAttribute.get_ApplyToOverrides() '. to ClrFunc.MarshalCLRObjectToV8(Handle* , Object netdata) to ClrFunc.MarshalCLRExceptionToV8(Handle* , Exception exception) to ClrFunc.Initialize(Handle* , Arguments* args) to initializeClrFunc(Handle* , Arguments* args)

Answer (score 0):

It's basically caused by using the wrong .net version. That's why it cannot find the javascriptserialiser class.

Please read this for more details:
[Cannot find JavaScriptSerializer in .Net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000811/cannot-find-javascriptserializer-in-net-4-0)