# UWP Json to C# conversion

Tags: c#, json, uwp, implicit-conversion

I want to serialize some json data I get from the web to classes and use the data, so I went to http://json2csharp.com/ and turned the json as below

```
json: [{"line_descr":"\u03a0\u0395\u0399\u03a1\u0391\u0399\u0391\u03a3 - 
\u0392\u039f\u03a5\u039b\u0391","line_descr_eng":"PEIRAIAS - VOYLA"}]
```

To this class:

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string line_descr { get; set; }
        public string line_descr_eng { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my code:

```
class LineName
{
    public async static Task<RootObject> GetLineName(int linecode)
    {
        var http = new HttpClient();
        var response = await http.GetAsync("http://telematics.oasa.gr/api/?act=getLineName&p1=962");
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
        var data = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

        return data;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string line_descr { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string line_descr_eng { get; set; }
}


    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RootObject myLine = await LineName.GetLineName(92);
        ResultTextBlock.Text = myLine.line_descr_eng;
    }
```

So when I try to get the data and display it in my textblock I get the error: line_descr_eng is null.

Can someone point where the fault is ? since the line_descr_eng should be
 PEIRAIAS - VOYLA but mine is null and after a lot of searching I cant find where the fault is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is an array, not an object, and you should deserialize it into an array.

```
public async static Task<RootObject[]> GetLineName(int linecode)
{
    var http = new HttpClient();
    var response = await http.GetAsync("http://telematics.oasa.gr/api/?act=getLineName&p1=962");
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject[]));
    var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
    var data = (RootObject[])serializer.ReadObject(ms);

    return data;
}
//...


 var myLines = await LineName.GetLineName(92);
 var myLine = myLines.FirstOrDefault();
```

Also you don't need a memory stream, you can read stream from the http response

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Comment: ok i tried this but it says it cant convert RootObject[] to RootObject the error is at the "return data". Can you specify it a bit more?? :)

Comment: @PanosPanosAthanasiou edited the post. Basically you need to change return type of the method and type of the variable to match the new data type.

Comment: ok it worked ^_^ thnx!! just the second var needs a different name from the first :)

So basicly we return an array and then we just get the first item from that array right ?

Comment: @PanosPanosAthanasiou yes, your json is an encoded array, this code decodes it as an array and gets the first element of it, or null if array is empty.

Comment: ok thanks a lot again, after your answer i was able to sort out everything ^_^ !!

Answer (score 0):

You simple can use the JavaScriptSerializer class instead of DataContractJsonSerializer like this:

Replace:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));
var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
var data = (RootObject)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

with this:

```
var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var test = ser.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

---

If you cannot find JavaScriptSerializer, then you have to do the simple following steps:

> 1. Right click References and do Add Reference, then from Assemblies->Framework select System.Web.Extensions.
> 2. Now you should be able to add the following to your class file:
>
>    ```
>    using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
>    ```

Cited from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15391388/5056173