# How to fix Error Type 'System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer' is not defined

Tags: json, vb.net, exception, serialization, namespaces

The super obvious way is to add reference to System.web

I did that. It doesn't work.

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1156313/465053).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

> Namespace:  System.Web.Script.Serialization
>
> Assembly: System.Web.Extensions (in System.Web.Extensions.dll)

Comment: Ah so that's how to find out how to know the dll to include.

Comment: How to "add a reference" for complete newbies, like me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx

Answer (score 11):

How to add System.Web.Extensions in Visual Studio 2012:

- Right-click your project.
- Click "Properties"
- Click the "References" tab on the left.
- Click the "Add" button
- Click "Assemblies"
- Click "Framework"
- Scroll down and find "System.Web.Extensions" and check the box next to it, then click OK, and save the Properties window.
- Type `Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization` at the top of your file (or, for C# `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;`)

I just had to figure this out, and it took me way longer than it should have to find the answer, so maybe that will help someone.